# unix find and replace characters with strings for multiple characters

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, command-line

I want to replace all occurrences of certain characters in my file with words. My question is, can I do that for all the characters using a single command. I am using the following command for replacing every occurrence of 'a' with 'apples'

```
sed 's/a/apple/g' sample.txt
```

I don't want to write 3 or 4 similar commands to replace every occurrence of 'b', 'c', 'd' with some words. Is there any way out to extend the above command to suit my need or do I need to use the same three times ?

Comment: Be careful when you get to replacing the `e` characters as it will affect the `e` in `apple` as well. You may want to investigate the Regexp features of sed, especially the "word boundary" characters.

Comment: @Intermernet What do you suggest I do in that case? I also noticed that using the command I mentioned, I get a replaced output in my terminal but the file contents are not modified.

Comment: Check out `sed -i`. It should allow in-place modification but is sometimes dangerous! copy the file first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-e` switch in sed to input multiple commands like this:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/a/apple/g' -e 's/b/bat/g' -e 's/c/cat/g'
```

Comment: This sounds good. But does it actually modify the contents of the file or does this simply display it on the terminal ? Using the sed command for me simply displays the changes in the terminal but When I open the file, I see the old unmodified  contents

Comment: I have added `-i.bak` flag to enable inline editing, this will save the changes in the file itself.

Comment: This worked perfectly. However, does the .bak serve as a backup file? If so, when is it actually useful ? Can't I simply use sed -i -e 's/a/apple/g' and so on ?

Comment: `.bak` keeps the original content of your file which is for safety measures if anything goes wrong then you can get the original file.

Comment: I get it. Now I get the logic.

Comment: I did that immediately but it asked me to wait for 5 minutes.